# Add BlurView in Expo app above navigation bar

Tags: expo

I have an [Expo](https://expo.io/) app where I want to use [`BlurView`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v15.0.0/sdk/blur-view.html) to create a modal effect. I want the blur to appear over everything, including the navigation bar. I am using [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) for navigation. Even if I add the `BlurView` as a child of the root screen it won't show above the navigation bar.

Comment: can you place you code here.